# Opencv 3.2 Python Video writing issue : Text on frames gets overlapped

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am a beginner in OpenCV python as well as on StackOverflow so please forgive me for any mistake. I am using OpenCV 3.2 with Python 3.6 for my image classification task. My task is to classify objects in frames and give its class label on that frame. When the final output video is written back, the text which has been put on the video gets overlapped.Below is my code.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r"D:\python\tank_video\All_vehicle.mp4")
length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
currentFrame = 0

# videowriter object
codc = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC))
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
w = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
h = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('classify_300_200_3.avi', fourcc, 15, (300,200))

                            "CLASSIFICATION CODE"

predictions =  [classes_names[i] for i in clf.predict(test_features)]
arr = np.array([])

j = 0
for prediction in predictions:
    pt = (0, 3 * image.shape[0] // 4)
    cv2.putText(image, prediction, pt ,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, [0, 255, 
    0], 2)
    np.append(arr,cv2.imwrite(str(j)+'.jpg',image))

out.write(image)
currentFrame += 1
cap.release()        
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output image has been attached herewith.[this is the screenshot of video output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZqYo.jpg) I want to show exactly one class label. The previous frame's label should not be displayed and current frame's label should not be overwritten on previous frame's label. Can anyone help me solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display only one class label, you should change the following:

```
for prediction in predictions:
    pt = (0, 3 * image.shape[0] // 4)
    cv2.putText(image, prediction, pt ,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, [0, 255, 
    0], 2)
    np.append(arr,cv2.imwrite(str(j)+'.jpg',image))
```

since that piece of code writes all classes detected to the image. For example, you can do:

```
# check if at least one class detected
if len(predictions)>0:
    # choose to display only the first class
    prediction = predictions[0]

    pt = (0, 3 * image.shape[0] // 4)
    cv2.putText(image, prediction, pt ,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, [0, 255, 
    0], 2)
    np.append(arr,cv2.imwrite(str(j)+'.jpg',image))
```